# One-to-one function

Tags: calculus, functions

How can I determine if the function is one-to-one .. I know that any odd function is 1-1 and any even function is NOT 1-1 but what about functions that are neither of those, like $x^3+5$ or $x^3+x^2+3$. How can I determine whether it is a one-to-one?

Comment: Who told you any odd function is one to one? That's not so.

Comment: $x^3-x$ is odd, but not one-to-one, because it has $3$ zeros.

Comment: It is also false that any even function is not 1-1. Any function whose domain is $\{0\}$ is even and 1-1.

Comment: One general way is to start with some $x$ and $y$ and assume that $f(x)=f(y)$ .If then you conclude that $x=y$ then the function is one-to-one .In your example :$$x^3+5=y^3+5$$ $$x^3=y^3$$ $$x=y$$ so the function is indeed one-to-one . Another idea is to look at the graph of the function .If there is a line parallel with the x-axis which intersects the graph in at least two points then the function in not one to one .

Comment: OK but when I try to apply this in the equation f(x)=x^2 which is obviously not one-to-one I get this y^2=x^2 should i remove the index with the index or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way in my opinion is to take your function, $f(x)$, and set it up so that $y=f(x)$. I'll use your function for example so that we have $y=x^3+x^2+3$. From here we want to perform a simple check for the existence of the inverse function (i.e. the function that when provided a value $f(x)$ will return $x$). To do this we just replace all the $x$s with $y$ and vise versa and see if its a function. So in your example
$$y=x^3+x^2+3 \Rightarrow x=y^3+y^2+3$$
which we can easily see that with the expression we ended up with, you can not solve for $y$ as a function of $x$. Thus meaning that the original equation had the same $y$-values for different $x$ values.
However say we have a line say $f(x)=3x+7$ which is one to one. Performing this check we get
$$y=3x+7 \Rightarrow x=3y+7$$
And since in the resulting equality, $y$ can be expressed as a function of $x$ ($y=\frac{1}{3}x-\frac{7}{3}$), the original function was one to one.

Answer (score 1):

There are $3$ distinct ways that I can remember as of now:

1. If the function is $y=f(x)$, then check the value of $f'(x)$. If $f'(x)\ge 0$ $\forall$ $x \in \{\mathbb{R}\}$, or $f'(x) \le 0$ $\forall$ $x \in \{\mathbb{R}\}$ , then $f(x)$ is one-one.
2. You can draw the graph of the function and perform the [horizontal line test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_line_test).
3. Assume $x_1=x_2$ when $x_1,x_2 \in $ domain and show that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.